Hosting swagger-ui behind nginx proxy
we have a setup where we have deployed springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui with Spring Boot 3.1.5. The spring boot server is running on port 8080. We have setup nginx so that all requests that start with /api are forwarded to spring boot:
location ~ ^/api(/|$) {
        rewrite ^/api(/|$)(.*)$ /$2 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;  # Forward requests to backend server
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; # per https://springdoc.org/index.html#how-can-i-deploy-springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui-behind-a-reverse-proxy
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-proto https; # per https://springdoc.org/index.html#how-can-i-deploy-springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui-behind-a-reverse-proxy
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix "/api"; # per https://springdoc.org/index.html#how-can-i-deploy-springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui-behind-a-reverse-proxy
    }

The last 3 lines are per what we could gather from this link. In our application.properties we have set:
server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE
server.use-forward-headers=true

Our expectation is that with this setup we should see the swagger UI at /api/swagger-ui/index.html. However when we navigate to that URL we see following:

and the developer tools in the browser show its trying to make request to /v3/api-docs to fetch the config whereas it should be making request to /api/v3/api-docs - we tested this URL works. All requests that Swagger UI is making to the backend need to be prefixed with /api. This is our core problem.
How can we fix this?

When our servers are behind proxy at that time we got this type of issue we have add below configuration in application.properties file.
server.forward-headers-strategy= framework

